# Aggregate Functions and Group By Problems

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

If we start with the following simple SQL statement which works.

```
SELECT sor.FPARTNO, sum(sor.FUNETPRICE)
FROM sorels sor
GROUP BY sor.FPARTNO
```

FPartNo is the part number and the Funetprice is obviously the net price. The user also wants the description and this causes a problem. If I follow up with this:

```
SELECT sor.FPARTNO, sor.fdesc, sum(sor.FUNETPRICE)
FROM sorels sor
GROUP BY sor.FPARTNO, sor.fdesc
```

If there are multiple variations of the description for that part number, typically very small variations in the text, then I don't actually aggregate on the part number. Make sense?

I'm sure this must be simple. How can I return the first fdesc that corresponds to the part number? Any of the description variations would suffice as they are almost entirely identical.

Edit: The description is a text field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't upgrade to SQL Server 2005 for a (max) type :-)

Try this. [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259342(SQL.80).aspx) works on blobs, but returns varchar for text. So the aggregate should work and you lose some data

```
SELECT
   sor.FPARTNO, MIN(SUBSTRING(sor.fdesc, 1, 8000)), sum(sor.FUNETPRICE)
FROM
    sorels sor
GROUP BY
    sor.FPARTNO, SUBSTRING(sor.fdesc, 1, 8000)
```

Comment: Don't you still have to use MIN or MAX, otherwise you will get spurious groups?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
SELECT sor.FPARTNO, MIN(sor.fdesc), sum(sor.FUNETPRICE) 
FROM sorels sor 
GROUP BY sor.FPARTNO
```

Or even **MAX** can do.

Try casting the NTEXT field

```
DECLARE @sorels TABLE(
        FPARTNO INT,
        fdesc NTEXT,
        FUNETPRICE FLOAT
)

SELECT sor.FPARTNO, MIN(CAST(sor.fdesc AS VARCHAR(4000))), sum(sor.FUNETPRICE)  
FROM @sorels sor  
GROUP BY sor.FPARTNO
```

Comment: I tried Max, and just now tried Min, and received the following error:

Error SQL Server Database Error: The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid in this subquery or aggregate expression.

Comment: What is the type of **sor.fdesc** ?

Comment: sor.fdesc is a text field as I said above in my previous edit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have not had a chance to test this, but it should be close.  If you were using SQL Server 2005, it would be a lot cleaner with CTEs.

```
SELECT agg.FPARTNO,
       (SELECT TOP 1 inner.FDESC FROM sorels inner WHERE inner.FPARTNO = agg.FPARTNO) FDESC,
       agg.FUNETPRICESUM
FROM   (SELECT sor.FPARTNO,
               sum(sor.FUNETPRICE) FUNETPRICESUM
        FROM sorels sor 
        GROUP BY sor.FPARTNO) agg
```

Comment: Inner is a reserved word, I believe.